# Как правильно использовать константы на java

Tags: java, const

В разных местах читал, что организуется так называемый пул констант в java. Что это и как оно обрамляется?
В качестве примера, чтобы было понятно что требуется привожу пример на C++

```
namespace constants
{
    const static int CONSTANT_NAME_0 = 0;
    const static int CONSTANT_NAME_1 = 1;
};
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/222519/

Comment: я видел эту статью, однако там ничего не говорится по поводу заданного вопроса.

Comment: Там именно про пул констант и говориться. Во всяком случае о другом понятии "пул констант", кроме как данных для внутреннего использования жавой, я не слушал. Есть просто константы. В жава для этого используют public static final поля класса или интерфейса. Вот кое-что на эту тему http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076481/learn-java/use-constant-types-for-safer-and-cleaner-code.html

Answer (score 1):

В спецификации языка Java вычитал, что лучше использовать перечисления для констант, например:

```
public enum Priorities
{
    HIGHEST(5),
    MIDDLE(1),
    LOWEST(2);
    private Priorities(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
    private int Value;
}
```

Использование перечисления:

```
Priorities.HIGHEST
```

В принципе такое использование меня устраивает. Поправьте если есть лучший способ использования.